PostgreSQL: using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
We are running PostgreSQL 13 on Azure Centos VM and found this problem from the logs followed by some slow commit and SET statements. The slow statement logs are only lasted for a period of less than 20sec. System metric are normal before or during the problem with a small spike in I/O wait upto 4%.

2024-08-15 16:21:59.048 CST,,,33328,,62b10ea0.8230,14,,2022-06-21 08:19:44 CST,1/0,0,LOG,00000,"using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding",,,,,,,,,"","autovacuum launcher"
2024-08-15 16:22:09.203 CST,,,58821,,66bdbaa7.e5c5,1,,2024-08-15 16:21:59 CST,148/0,0,LOG,00000,"using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding",,,,,,,,,"","autovacuum worker"
2024-08-15 16:22:09.253 CST,"user_w","user_db",53133,"10.0.0.85:58698",66bdb747.cf8d,1,"COMMIT",2024-08-15 16:07:35 CST,46/0,0,LOG,00000,"duration: 21525.916 ms  statement: COMMIT",,,,,,,,,"app - 10.0.0.14:34356","client backend"
2024-08-15 16:22:09.253 CST,"user_w","user_db",48595,"10.0.0.68:33334",66bdb4d3.bdd3,1,"COMMIT",2024-08-15 15:57:07 CST,15/0,0,LOG,00000,"duration: 21383.608 ms  statement: COMMIT",,,,,,,,,"app - 10.0.0.18:36088","client backend"
2024-08-15 16:22:09.253 CST,"user_w","user_db",50680,"10.0.0.68:33714",66bdb5a9.c5f8,1,"COMMIT",2024-08-15 16:00:41 CST,25/0,0,LOG,00000,"duration: 20137.894 ms  statement: COMMIT",,,,,,,,,"app - 10.0.0.18:36400","client backend"
2024-08-15 16:22:09.253 CST,"user_w","user_db",42490,"10.0.0.68:60644",66bdb2d6.a5fa,1,"COMMIT",2024-08-15 15:48:38 CST,63/0,0,LOG,00000,"duration: 18201.579 ms  statement: COMMIT",,,,,,,,,"app - 10.0.0.18:36274","client backend"
2024-08-15 16:22:09.253 CST,"user_w","user_db",52468,"10.0.0.68:34266",66bdb6e0.ccf4,1,"COMMIT",2024-08-15 16:05:52 CST,30/0,0,LOG,00000,"duration: 20438.055 ms  statement: COMMIT",,,,,,,,,"app - 10.0.0.16:52796","client backend"
2024-08-15 16:22:09.269 CST,"user_w","user_db",55877,"10.0.0.52:47198",66bdb8e6.da45,2,"SET",2024-08-15 16:14:30 CST,57/0,0,LOG,00000,"duration: 3843.296 ms  statement: SET application_name='app - 10.0.0.4:38932';",,,,,,,,,"app - 10.0.0.4:38932","client backend"
2024-08-15 16:22:09.269 CST,"user_w","user_db",55278,"10.0.0.70:59560",66bdb890.d7ee,1,"SET",2024-08-15 16:13:04 CST,43/0,0,LOG,00000,"duration: 20042.606 ms  statement: SET application_name='app - 10.0.0.16:52848';",,,,,,,,,"app -10.0.0.16:52848","client backend"

From what I can check the collector using IPv6 , IPv6 is enabled as of now and stats are getting updated. We only logging slow statements and the first entry of slow commit statement took 20sec completed at 2024-08-15 16:22:09.253 CST which is on calculation might started before the first entry of stats collector log at 2024-08-15 16:21:59.048 CST. We are unable to make a conclusion where the problem actually started with stats collector or the transactions and the cause of issue? This issue auto resolves in 10-20sec.
UPDATE
I have noticed when the system working normal there is no UDP socket for postmaster if I run netstat -n -u -p. However files under pg_stat_temp directory is getting updated and I can see the stats collector process under process list. Why is there no  visible UDP socket under postmaster?

Disk being temporarily overwhelmed and so very slow to confirm fsync can explain both the slow COMMIT and the stale stats.  On the cloud the disks are presumably not physically attached to the machine, so it could also be a network glitch driving the disk glitch.

Thanks for the comment. Yeah i suspected the same, but is there any way i can verify the same? But then how the SET connected to fsync ?

I don't know how SET would be directly tied to fsync.  It might just be an innocent bystander.  Maybe it triggers a write to some log file, which then gets caught up in the mess.

As jjane indicated above in comments this is indeed caused by disk availability issue impacted by platform problem in Azure and it auto-resolves 10-20secs. For those who having this problem frequently please check below things as well

Overloaded Disk - If it too frequent consider pointing pg_stat_tmp to ram disk
postmaster udp socket created for Ipv6 but it disabled later- for this you may have to either restart service to create socket using ipv4 or enable ipv6 for loopback interface

